# React property XXX is missing in type 'YYY' but required in type 'ZZZ'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, intrinsicattributes

```
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
export interface AvatarSize {
  avatarSize: number;
}

export interface PageInterface extends AvatarSize {
  user: {
    permaLink: string;
  };
}

const data = {
  user: {
    permaLink:
      "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1590698933947-a202b069a861?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8MTF8fGhhcHB5fGVufDB8fDB8fA%3D%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60"
  },
  avatarSize: 50
};

const App = () => <Page user={data} />; // user is 

const Page = (props: PageInterface) => (
  <PageLayout user={props.user} avatarSize={props.avatarSize} />
);

const PageLayout = (props: PageInterface) => (
  <NavigationBar user={props.user} avatarSize={props.avatarSize} />
);

const NavigationBar = (props: PageInterface) => (
  <Link to={props.user.permaLink}>
    <Avatar avatarSize={props.avatarSize} />
  </Link>
);

const Avatar = (props: AvatarSize) => (
  <div>Avatar Size: {props.avatarSize}</div>
)

export default App;
```

[image]

I just started studying React and the above source throws an error but I have no idea how to sort this out. I think it might be related to typescript interface not react.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you have defined interface of `data` not page props. There are two things which you can do to fix it, either change the type of props or send `user` and `avatarSize` directly into props.

**Approach 1:**

```
const Page = (props: { user: PageInterface }) => (
  <PageLayout user={props.user.user} avatarSize={props.user.avatarSize} />
);
```

**Approach 2:** (Recommended)

```
const App = () => <Page user={data.user} avatarSize={data.avatarSize} />;
```